# a ruby regex that will find a json object in a string

Tags: ruby, regex, json

I have an API plugin for wordpress that is suppose to respond with valid json, but certain clients have added other plugins which add html to the response making the response unparseable. I need to find a regex that will match only the json object, so I can disregard any other text in the response.

```
"{\"status\":\"ok\",\"plugin_version\":\"1.2.6\",\"post\":{\"id\":7598}}<div>disregard</div>"
```

I want to match only this

```
"{\"status\":\"ok\",\"plugin_version\":\"1.2.6\",\"post\":{\"id\":7598}}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match from the first `{` up to the last `}`, that is:

```
string = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"plugin_version\":\"1.2.6\",\"post\":{\"id\":7598}}<div>disregard</div>"
string.match( /{.+}/ )[0]
=> "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"plugin_version\":\"1.2.6\",\"post\":{\"id\":7598}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Pretty messy and depends on your JSON structure but how about:

```
/(\"{\\"status\\":\\"\w*\\",\\"plugin_version\\":\\"(\d|.)+\\",\\"post\\":{\\"id\\":\d+}}")/i
```

Demo on rubular: http://rubular.com/r/iycmawqNUo

*EDIT*: made regex capture the JSON string as opposed to just match against it

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sub(/}<([^>]*)>.*</\1>\s*$/, "}")`:

```
> t = "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"plugin_version\":\"1.2.6\",\"post\":{\"id\":7598}}<div>disregard</div>"
=> "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"plugin_version\":\"1.2.6\",\"post\":{\"id\":7598}}<div>disregard</div>"

> t.sub!(/}<([^>]*)>.*<\/\1>\s*$/, "}")
=> "{\"status\":\"ok\",\"plugin_version\":\"1.2.6\",\"post\":{\"id\":7598}}"

> JSON.parse(t)
=> {"status"=>"ok", "plugin_version"=>"1.2.6", "post"=>{"id"=>7598}}
```